# PrestaShop1.5.5.0 module Authorize.net AIM (1.4.4) not showing on Payment Page

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net, prestashop-1.5

I am using PrestaShop 1.5.5.0 and I have installed Authorize.net AIM (1.4.4) from the Admin's modules Payment and Gateways tab.

I have Provided Login Id and Keys for Authorize.net Terminal Account and enabled the Test mode.

The Authorize.net module isn't showing on my payment page. In fact it is giving me the following errror:

`No payment modules have been installed.`

Please Guide me ! My website is ready to go live.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the administration panel.

Check if you have activated a currency

`Menu Localization` > `Currencies` > Check if your currency (it seems to be the US dollar) is activated (green icon)

`Menu Modules` > `Payment` > Check if `Authorize.net AIM` is checked in the `Restriction module payment` panel.

Look at the config.xml file :
need_instance should be 1 : [prestashop forum link](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/238123-authorizenet-aim-wont-display-on-checkout-in-153/#entry1347657).

```
<need_instance>1</need_instance>
```

---

---

**Module bug** ==> http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PNM-1375

```
**This issue has been fixed. This is simply for informational purposes**

Authorize.net AIM module is corrupted/broken when choosing to disable another payment option. 

Went through the store and decided to remove the Bank Cheque option. 

CC options disappeared from Payment page. Disabled/enabled Authorize module - no change. 

Decided to uninstall/re-install module and CC options reappeared. 

Had turned back on Bank Cheque option while testing - decided to remove it and immediately the CC options disappeared again. 

Uninstall/re-install of module brought back CC options.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However as per your mentioned page , I can see the below table 

`Currency restrictions   authorizeaim`

`Dollar --`

`Customer currency --`

`Shop default currency --`

Please notice there is NO CHECK BOX. Is this any bug?

Very simply, for currency restriction options, under the Authorize.net column I just get hyphens, no check boxes

Comment: Menu Localization > Currencies > Check if your currency is activated (green icon)

Comment: Yes ! It is Activated ! Only one currency which DOLLAR(USD)

Comment: I am confused on what to do.I saw your link and get confused as my all payment module is either deactivated or deleted. Only Authorize.net is enabled. If you can please guide me!

Comment: Try uninstall of your payment module, also  Authorize.net AIM (1.4.4). Then reinstall it and configure it. Try to buy something with it, it  should be okay. Then if you have other payment modules to install, just install the ones you want to use (never desactivate if I have understood the bug). I never used this plugin, so I can't tell you more.

Comment: If you know IT Crowd : "Have you tried to turn off and on again ? " It seems to be the solution to your problem. :)

Comment: Wait, Maybe there is another solution : http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/238123-authorizenet-aim-wont-display-on-checkout-in-153/#entry1347657

Comment: I already done this one <need_instance>1</need_instance> but nothing works :-(

Comment: can u give me an idea on how I can implement Authorize.net manually without module

Comment: Well, so I f... don't know. Sorry. :/ Try to uninstall your payment modules and reinstall just AIM and tell us. I never user AIM, but here is a link : http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/

Comment: Thanks and uninstalling - installing doesnt seems to work :-(

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you more.

Comment: What I would finally try is to install a new prestashop elsewhere and activate only this module payment and test if it works or not. If it doesn't, then do your own module (it is maybe easy), if it does, then redo your prestashop website if it is not too long.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net aim module requires ssl activated to work. There are two ways to make the module visible. Either you install ssl on your shop or change the module code. I've gone through the same situation. I got the positive result after enabling ssl. Thank YOu

Comment: Yes you are right but you answered a bit later..the issue was same, the SSl, 
During debugging I commented that SSL part to check its workings and it worked !